# Linux - permissions on a file for different groups

Tags: linux, file-permissions

### Context

I have a file I want some people to share with me.
There are 3 groups involved.

We are 6 people : Emily, Sandy, Beatrice, Josh, Antoine and me, Alain.

Group1 : Alain,Josh

Group2 : Sandy, Emily

Group3 : Antoine, Beatrice.

There is one file to access : theFile.txt

Here are the permissions:

1) Group1 : read write execute.

2) Group2 : read execute

3) Group3 : read write

### Question

How could I achieve this with no file copy (need to be in sync && imagine if we do that on multiple directories and files).

I don't figure out how i can achieve this.

Comment: You could do this using POSIX ACLs, here is an SO post on this subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351622/linux-directory-permissions-for-different-groups

Comment: I think you can't since there is no descending right permissions across those groups. One group will end up being able to write, or able to execute, where it may not, according to the rules you give. -- Are you sure group 2 may not write, or Group 3 may not execute ?

Comment: As it seems posix acl do the trick :) Bohuslav would you mind making an answer for a reward?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Unix & Linux (unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

try this tutorial....

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialManagingGroups.html

and this

http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php

hope it will help you...